# Complex Integrals (No Residue allowed)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> [image]
>
> Complete the integrals along curve $C$
>
> a) $\displaystyle\int_C\frac1z\ \mathrm dz$
>
> b) $\displaystyle\int_Cf(z)\ \mathrm dz;\quad[f(a)]^2=z\ \&\ f(1)=1$
>
> c) $\displaystyle\int_Cg(z)\ \mathrm dz;\quad g(z)=\sqrt[4]z\ \&\ g(1)=i$

Comment: What is the curve...?

Comment: I think it is better to post these problems separately and show some effort as to how far you have come and we can help. I you are sleep deprived, take some caffeine pills. We have all been there, done that...

Comment: @Nameless It's in the imgur link. It's some contour starting at (1,0) that takes 2 loops (CCW) around the origin and ends at (e,0)

Comment: @imranfat I guess I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Close the curve by adding the segment $[1,e]$ with the proper orientation to it. I will call the new curve $c^{+}$. Use the definition of index of the curve in the origin:

$2\pi i Ind_{c^{+}}(0)=\int_{c^{+}}\frac{1}{z} dz=\int_{c}\frac{1}{z} dz+\int_{[1,e]}\frac{1}{z} dz=\int_{c}\frac{1}{z} dz+(Log(1)-Log(e))=\int_{c}\frac{1}{z} dz-1$

Hence $\int_{c}\frac{1}{z} dz=4\pi i +1$

b) $f(z)=\sqrt z$ or $f(z)=-\sqrt z$ but since $f(1)=1$, we deduce $f(z)=\sqrt z$. A primitive of $f(z)$ is $\frac{2}{3}z^{\frac{3}{2}}$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Hence, $\int_{c}f(z)dz=\frac{2}{3}(e^{\frac{3}{2}}-1)$

c) $g(z)$, defined as you did, is not the function you are looking for, since $g(1)$ would be $1$. So I am assuming that our function $g$ is *one* of the fourth roots of $z$, in particular the one verifying the condition $g(1)=i$. This is the case for $g(z)=|z|^{\frac{1}{4}}(cos(\frac{arg(z)+2\pi}{4})+isin(\frac{arg(z)+2\pi}{4}))$, i.e. $g(z)=iz^{\frac{1}{4}}$. A primitive of $g(z)$ is $\frac{4i}{5}z^{\frac{5}{4}}$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Hence, $\int_{c}g(z)dz=\frac{4i}{5}(e^{\frac{5}{4}}-i^{\frac{5}{4}})$

Comment: What is this definition you used of index? Can you elaborate the "2πiIndc+(0)"?

Comment: The index of a curve in a point is the number of times the curve loops around that point, and it is given by the formula

$Ind_{c}(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c} \frac{1}{w-z}dw$

Comment: It took me a while to see it but I understand now. Very clever!

Comment: This answer is reasonable, but the question-asker should understand that using "index" is scarcely different from using "residues", which is very easy, in any case. That is, even if it's "necessary" in the context of coursework and grades, it is somewhat perverse to avoid using residues in a situation for which the idea is perfect/designed.